# Real-Time data from TextFile

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Good afternoon for Everyone!

I have a question about Real-Time data/values reading in ASP.NET.

I have project where I want to show actual temperautre status. My Thermomether sending every 10 seconds a temperature status to the textfile and I am reading from that in my ASP.NET webform.
But I don´t know what is the right way? Should I set up automatic update or there is anorhter way???

Thanks you very much for your advices.

Comment: Assuming you have no choice in waiting for the text file to update, instead of alternatives such as piping the data directly to your program. You may want to consider using the [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-5.0) to get notified when the file is written to.

Comment: And with FileSystemWatcher I can getting in realtime value from that txtFile?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this with FileSystem Watcher :

```
FileSystemWatcher fwatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
fwatcher.Path = Path.GetDirectoryName({your file full path}); ;
fwatcher.Filter = Path.GetFileName({your file full path});
//types of events to watch 
fwatcher.NotifyFilter=NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName;
fwatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

And then you can capture the changes in order to reload your text file when needed like the exemple below : (

```
private void Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)

{

    //insert your logic here to reload your file and make your "things"
}
```

Comment: Please look down below I have written code but someting went wrong ....
Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know - that RealTime stream is not running...
What is wrong?

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
    {




        TextReader tr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Help\H1.txt");


        Label1.Text = tr.ReadLine() + " °C";
        Label1.Text  += tr.ReadToEnd();

        tr.Close();

        FileSystemWatcher fwatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

        

        fwatcher.Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\Help\H1.txt"); 
        fwatcher.Filter = Path.GetFileName(@"C:\Help\H1.txt");

        //types of events to watch 
        fwatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        fwatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;


       fwatcher.Changed += Changed;




    }

    public void Changed(Object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        TextReader tr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Help\H1.txt");
        Label1.Text = tr.ReadLine() + " °C";
        Label1.Text += tr.ReadToEnd();

        tr.Close();

    }
}
```